# Ember.js - How to not reload the model on the route loading

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am developing an app where there is a huge list of items, loaded from the server by ember-data. This lists can be filtered by different fields, like date.

When you load this route for the first time, it is filtered by date: it only loads the current year items. However, the user can change those filters.

When you transition to another route and come back, the visible filters are the same as when you left, ember seems to remember them. However, since the model is loaded by the route before the controller exists and the filters are available, it loads all the current year ones.

Therefore, the result is that the user is seeing a list of all current-year items, and a set of filters that may not match.

What I would love is for the route to not reload the model if it is already available, so to save time and network; but any solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your model hook? The more you can share on top of the model hook, the easier to help :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You could move the GET to the controller which will not be regenerated on route change, if the controller is already present all your previous models and filters are still present
2. Get the last selected filter options from the controller in beforeModel:... or model:... method to load your data via query (if possible)
3. If you´re sure all the data is already loaded use peekRecords to avoid a new network request

Comment: I've tried to remove the "model" hook from the route and load it from the controller "init", but the result is not satisfactory. Instead of keeping the model on revisit, it is replaced by a few empty items. ```init``` seems to be only called the first time, which is a pity because it could solve everything. I don't yet get why. I'll try to set up a test account on a testing server to show.